Verification of bounded linear operator.
This is just an exercise that says: $T$ is an operator from $X$ to $Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two normed  linear spaces.If there exists one open set $D \subset X$  s.t. $\exists c$,$\forall x\in D$,$ \|Tx\|\leq c$, then $T$ is bounded.
I invisaged to put every $x \in B(x_0,r)\subset D \subset X$ with translation and scale operator $T_1$ and $T_2$ to the unit ball $B=\{ x\in X: \|x\| \leq1\}$ where $x_0 \in D$ is the center of the ball i.e $B=T_2T_1(B(x_0,r))$. Then to some extent $B(x_0,r)$ works just like $B$.
But I found that $T_1$ as the translation operator is not linear and I couldn't continue my work. Does the idea work? If not, how to solve this question or it's not right at all? I would appreciate it if you can help me.

Hint: For any $x$ there exists $n$ such that $x_0+\frac 1  n x \in B(x_0,r)$. How big should  $n$ to be?

But how about the next steps?I choose that $n$ and let $y_n=x_0+\frac{1}{n}x$ i.e.$x=n(y_n-x_0)$.And finally I still need to show$|Tx|=|T(n(y_n-x_0))|\leq n(|Ty_n|+|Tx_0|)\leq 2nc$. But I cant restrict $n$ anymore

I did mention that $n$ can be controlled.

You mean that I may choose the supremum of $n$ with respect to all $x$ in $X$?Because $n$ is related to $x$.

Final hint: $x_0+\frac r {2|x||}x \in B(x_0,r)$. I am pretty sure this question is  a duplicate and I will be criticized if I post an answer.

Sorry I just misled what you meant. I thought $n$ is a positive integer and cant continue. I see that and thank you a lot!
